# tslint warning should failed build process

Tags: angular, build, ionic2, tslint

I am using Angular 5 and Ionic 3. I would like to fail my application build process, if I will get any tslint warning.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Use [tslint-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-loader) and in the config file set the `emitErrors` to `true`.